# Print numbers inside react component with map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is probably an easy one, but I can't seem to figure it out. How do I print the numbers in order inside my list? If I print index some of the numbers will be skipped due to my conditions? Can I set a count++ somewhere inside my map-function inside my condition so it will increase every time a list-item is printed?

```
export const MFAPaging = ({rootStore, page}) => {
  let count = 1;

  return (
    <div className="components-paging-brder">
      <div className="components-paging">
        <ul>
          {rootStore.mfaStore.links.map((item, index) =>
              item && item.includePage ? 
              <li className={page == index ? 'active' : ''} key={index}>{count}</li>
              : undefined 
            )}
        </ul>
        <MFAButtons rootStore={rootStore} page={page} />
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you try to return `null` instead of `undefined` in your fallback? Or filtering the array before map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can filter the array, and then your indexes will be cool in your .map (never use .map to filter, you already have build-in functions)

```
{rootStore.mfaStore.links.filter((item)=> item && item.includePage).map((item, index) =>
    <li className={page == index ? 'active' : ''} key={index}>{count}</li>
)}
```

For questions comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment the count variable on each iteration. You can try the following. It should solve your problem.

```
<li className={page == index ? 'active' : ''} key={index}>{count++}</li>
```

`++` at the end is important. `count++` will first read the current `count` variable's value then increment its value.

Comment: in these cases always go with built in functions like .filter

Comment: This answer is focused on how OP can increment the counter variable inside the expression. Also it should work without the filter

Answer (score 0):

Try to use foreach, because if u try to use map, your result will be like a array with some undefined values: `[<li></li>, undefined, <li></li>]`, and foreach prevent it.

```
const renderList = ({fullList}) => {
  let counter = 0;
  const renderList = [];
  list.foreach((data, index) => {
    if (data && data.includePage) renderList.push(<li>{++counter}</li>);
  });
  return renderList;
}
```